# Is Azure ML Studio support to import Excel file as Dataset?

Tags: azure, ml-studio

I am using Azure ML Studio and trying to upload an excel file as Dataset. However, I am not getting option for it. Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: you can convert excel file to csv easily, is it not an option for you ?

Comment: @Thomas yes that is an workaround option, aware of it. But how could I do it with XLS file without convert.

Comment: I think you will find that the simplest  option - convert it to csv - will be far and away the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to read an Excel file in an `Execute Python Script` module of an experiment of Azure Machine Learning Studio. According to the offical document [`Execute Python machine learning scripts in Azure Machine Learning Studio][1]`, there are two ways to do that as below.

1. To upload the Excel file to Azure Blob Storage, then follow the section [`Accessing Azure Storage Blobs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/execute-python-scripts#accessing-azure-storage-blobs) to read it by using Azure Blob Storage SDK for Python.
2. Refer to the section [`Importing existing Python script modules`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/execute-python-scripts#import-modules) to package the Excel file with other required Python packages as a zip file, then to read it from the directory named `Script Bundle` of the zip file by automatically extracting by Azure ML Stodio.

As reference, I will show you the detail steps for the second solution as below.

1. I prepared an excel file named `test.xlsx`, which content as below.

   [image]
2. Download the [`xlrd`](https://pypi.org/project/xlrd/#files) package file [`xlrd-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b0/16/63576a1a001752e34bf8ea62e367997530dc553b689356b9879339cf45a4/) from its PyPi.org page, then to extract these compressed files of it to a directory `test` and compress them with `test.xlsx` to a zip file `test.zip`, as below.

   [image]
3. I uploaded the zip file `test.zip` as a dataset to Azure ML Studio, and assemble it with a `Execute Python Script` module.

   [image]
4. Here is my sample code. I tried to use `os.getcwd()`, `os.listdir()`, `os.listdir('Script Bundle')` with logs to find the correct path for reading a file in the zip file.

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
       import os
       print(os.getcwd())
       print(os.listdir())
       print(os.listdir('Script Bundle'))

       import xlrd
       file = 'Script Bundle/test.xlsx'
       data = xlrd.open_workbook(file)
       print([sheet.name for sheet in data.sheets()])

       print('Input pandas.DataFrame #1:\r\n\r\n{0}'.format(dataframe1))

       return dataframe1,
   ```

It works in `Anaconda 4.0/Python 3.5`, the logs as below.

[image]

Hope it helps.